# Get-AzDataFactoryV2 : HTTP Status Code: NotFound

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I wrote this `Azure PowerShell` script

```
$DataFactoryName = "BI-Dashboard-DataFactory-2"
$ResourceGroupName = "BI-Dashboard-ResourceGroup-2"
$ResourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName

# Write-Output $DataFactory.DataFactoryName 
if(-not $ResourceGroup)
 {
   $ResourceGroup= New-AzResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -location 'westeurope'
   Write-Output " Resource Group Created Successfully "      
}
else 
{
 # Resource Group Already Exists
 Write-Output "Resource Group Exists" 
}

$DataFactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -Name $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName

 if (-not $DataFactory)
 {
    $DataFactory = Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceGroup.Location -Name $DataFactoryName
    Write-Output " Data Factory Created Successfully "
 }
 else 
 {
  Write-Output "Data Factory {0} Already Exists" -f $DataFactory.DataFactoryName 
 }
```

some time ago and if `Resource` or `Data Factory` does not exist it didn't throw any exception, it simply executed if block. 
[image]

I have created a new subscription and executing the same `PowerShell` script against new subscription and now receives this exception in red color as well as execution of if block. I need to know whether something is changed in `Azure Resource Manager` when its accepting this `PowerShell` request to display error message or this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive this error message "Get-AzDataFactoryV2 : HTTP Status Code: NotFound", when the resource doesn't exists in the resource group.

The script first looks for the resource group exists or not, then it will check for the data factory exists in the resource group or not.

If the resource exists gives the results, else it throws the error message.

**Example:** In my resource group named chpradeep, I have a data factory name "chepra".

**Case1:** (Success) If I run the below cmdlet gives the results because the data factory named chepra exists in the resource group.

Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "chpradeep" -Name chepra

[image]

**Case2:** (Error) If I run the below cmdlet gives the error message because the data factory named alpha doesn't exists in the resource group.

Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "chpradeep" -Name alpha

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to handle this exception without displaying these red error messages. because when i follow the same process to create self-hosted integration runtime. it does not display error message even though it does not exist

Comment: after more investigation this red coloring is the default behavior of Azure PowerShell and are classified as non-terminating errors and can be changed to white color through powershell tricks

Answer (score 0):

use:-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue at end of command